# Selenium XPath Invalid Syntax

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]//*[contains(string(.), "THE_TEXT_STRING_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR")]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contactFirstName"]').send_keys(firstName)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contactLastName"]').send_keys(lastName)
```

This one would say for an example, it'd say "SyntaxError: invalid syntax",
the second one.

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]//*[contains(string(.), "THE_TEXT_STRING_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR")]')
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

So, I really have no clue what to do, everything that's underneath the code, says invalid syntax, and if it's above it says unexpected EOF...

Comment: What is the value of `THE_TEXT_STRING_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR`? Share the xpath that is actually used in runtime?

Comment: @AlexeyR.     element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]//*[contains(string(.), "THE_TEXT_STRING_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR")]')
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contactFirstName"]').send_keys(firstName)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contactLastName"]').send_keys(lastName)

This one would say for an example, it'd say "SyntaxError: invalid syntax",
the second one.
So, I really have no clue what to do, everything that's underneath the code, says invalid syntax, and if it's above it says unexpected EOF...

Answer (score 0):

You have the broken syntax of the entire expression. You should change single quote to double quote and close your expression with `)]')`. Your line should look like:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]//*[contains(string(.), "THE_TEXT_STRING_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR")]')
```

You should also be aware of you can break the syntax if your `THE_TEXT_STRING_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR` will include some special characters like quotes.

Comment: With this code though now, whatever I put underneath it, it says invalid syntax "driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="liveAgentChatInput"]').send_keys("TEST"):"

Comment: Also, when I put only the code you gave me, it says SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225/python-unexpected-eof-while-parsing